# Diagnose python memory usage

Tags: python, linux

I am migrating a project from python 2.5 to python 2.7 and one process is using about 4x the amount of memory that it did before. I used pmap to look at the process and I see one section that seems to be using the most memory:

```
10011000 245208K rwx--    [ anon ]
```

First, from reading online, the anon sections are ones that have been allocated by malloc? Is there any way I can get more specific info on why there is so much memory being allocated vs python 2.5? I should note that its not just python version changing, its running on an embedded system and I have upgraded all the libraries and user land tools, but the kernel version is the same. Not sure if any of that could have an impact.

Comment: use valgrind on the application.valgrind --tool=memcheck http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/README.valgrind , it will give you an idea on if there is any leak

Comment: i have seen cases were glibc changes cause memory usage increase.   malloc uses excessive memory for multi-threaded applications  http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11261